# enable to download Nanogest SDK

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition

I'm trying to developp and android application that's recognize hand gesture. I'm trying tu use Nanogest SDK http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/
But I don't know from where can I download the Nanogest SDK for android?

Thank you

Comment: How about googling "Android SDK" ? The first result is not working for you ?

Comment: I mean Nanogest SDK not android SDK thx

Answer (score 1):

try this , go to media kits and then download
http://www.nanocritical.com/about.html

Comment: Thank you for your response but this link doesn't contain the SDK. I contacted them directly but I didn't receive any response..

Comment: they might have removed it, yes i also tried to contact them and they are not replying.